# window.open losing focus when opened from dojo dijit.dialog

Tags: xpages, dojo

I am opening a dialog box from my application using Dojo 1.8 - dijit.Dialog. On the Dialog window there is an icon to display the help. If this help is clicked it will open a new window  (using window.open)and will show help text.

The code works in Firefox but not in IE (All version of IE 8,9,10). The help window always goes to the back of the parent window. Alt+Tab also did not bring the help window to front. (When you are on other screen and then Alt+Tab brings the help window).

If call the function directly in a page without dialog then it works in IE as well. If I use the dojo 1.6 then the code works in IE. The problem is only in dojo 1.8

I have used autofocus to false, refocus to false and window.focus in the help window. But nothing helps. Help or pointers on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Note: The application is on Xpage, so you can ignore some tags.The problem is related to the Dojo

Code is something like this. there are 3 pages. The first page contains 2 Javascrip function and a links to open dialog. The second page is a dialog and contain a link to open Help page using window.open. Third page is just a text for Help.

**Page 1**

```
<a onclick="javascript:modalwindojo('Dijit Dialog','FirstDialog.xsp','dialog1')" href="#">modalwindow</a>
```

**Page 2** - Dialog page

```
<a href="javascript:openHelp('FirstHelp.xsp');" id="link2">Help</a>
```

**Page 3** - Help Page
Just text with onloadevent as `<script>window.focus();</script>`

JavaScript Function

```
<script>
function openHelp(helpUrl){  

    windowHelpObjectReference = window.open(helpUrl,   
            "Help", "resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,status=yes,width=700,height=500");   
    windowHelpObjectReference.focus(); 

} 
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
function modalwindojo(dtitle, link, dialogId)
{
   var dlg = dijit.byId(dialogId);
   if (!dlg) { 
    dlg = new dijit.Dialog({
    title : dtitle,
        href : link,
        autofocus :false ,
        refocus : false 

        }, dojo.byId(dialogId));
  }

 // dlg.startup();
  dlg.show();

}

</script>
```

Comment: You need to be specific with your IE version, they all behave differently.

Comment: Opening a window from a dialog sounds like a UI pattern your users will not appreciate. Have you considered a Dojo panel instead? It also can load an url

Comment: It happens in all the IE versions(8,9 & 10). We have been migrating from 1.6 to 1.8, so we have not thought of Dojo Panel or any other solution. If we cannot solve this then we need to revisit the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dijit panel instead of a window. Opening a window is risky: a popup blocker might prevent it,  if one is already open with the same name it doesn't get in the foreground. If you use tabs there is no logic for the user which of the popups belongs to which tab. A popup might get forced to open in a tab by browser configuration.

In short : you are better off with a panel.